# ColdFusion - Cached CFC not refreshing

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfc

Running ColdFusion 10 Update 18 on Server 2012 R2 with IIS 8.5. I've made changes to a CFC, and created a new CFC file as well to test. The changes I made aren't being reflected, and the new file returns a 404 File Not Found.

I've done the following:

- Checked the Jakarta virtual directory exists
- Removed and readded the site with the CF Web Config tool
- Cleared the WEB-INF class temporary folder
- Clicked all the Clear Cache buttons in CF Admin
- Unchecked all cache options in CF Admin

I inherited this setup and do not have any prior ColdFusion experience. Thanks!

Comment: What is used to create / interact with the cfc?

Comment: We're using ColdBox. I think that is what you are asking.

Comment: If using coldbox, try to reinit.

Comment: To reinit, I just load index.cfm?fwreinit=1 correct? This worked on my test VM, but not on our production. They should be identical systems.

Comment: Are you attempting to browse to the cfc directly, or is there a cfm page that calls it?

Comment: @JStacy Not necessarily the same. The `/config/ColdBox.cfc` might define [different settings for a local vs production environment](http://blog.coldbox.org/blog/tip-of-the-week-using-environment-control-in-coldbox). You should see if the `reinitPassword` variable is set in there. It defaults to 1, but in production you [*really* should change it](http://blog.coldbox.org/blog/tip-of-the-week-securing-your-applications-reinit)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add some supplemental functionality to your application.

I adapted this to your `fw1init=1` query param.

**Your intercept in index.cfm or futher upstream if necessary.**

```
<cfscript>
if (find('404;',CGI.query_string)){
    location('index.cfm?fwreinit=1'); 
}   
</cfscript>
```

**In your Application.cfc**

```
<cfscript>
public boolean function OnRequestStart(required string Target){
if (structkeyExists(url, 'fwreinit') and url.fwreinit){
    if (isDefined('application')){
        structClear(application);
        onApplicationStart();
    }
    if (isDefined('session')){
        structClear(session);
        onSessionStart();
    }
}
}   
</cfscript>
```